# Operations between django objects

Tags: django, orm

I am trying to perform operations between 2 django objects. Can you suggest on how to proceed on this?

I have 2 objects

```
class v_Sale(models.Model):
    Key_Variable=models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    Sales = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class v_Threshold(models.Model):
    Key_Variable=models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    Threshold = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

I want to calculate (Sales-Threshold) and save it in a new variable.

Comment: OK, so what's the problem?

Comment: In my view, I am doing the following.        db_Sale= v_Sale.objects.all()
    db_Threshold=v_Threshold.objects.all() . But when I try to write the code for the operation, I get the error "Exception Value: 
unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'QuerySet' and 'QuerySet'"

Comment: You seem to have neglected to describe "the operation" (which you should do in an update to the question, not a comment). But isn't the error enough to tell you? Querysets are collections of objects; what are you intending to do with two separate collections?

Comment: So, I want to do the subtraction based on Key_Variable which is the primary key... Something like this..  (x=db_Sale - db_Threshold)

Comment: The `Key_Variable` is string in both model classes. You can't substract strings in python. Also please follow python coding conventions: snake_case for properties and methods, PascalCase for classes.

Comment: I get your point, but I want to do the subtraction on the Sales and Threshold metrices.

Comment: You should avoid using strings i.e. `CharField` as primary key. The best practice is to use surrogate keys.

Comment: `Sales` and `Treshold` are strings too. You CANNOT substract strings in python.

Answer (score -1):

You can override the magic methods(`__add__` or `__sub__` or whatever you need) and let them do what you need.
Example:

```
class v_Sale(models.Model):
    Key_Variable=models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    Sales = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return eval(self.Sales.value + " + " + other.Threshold.value)


class v_Threshold(models.Model):
    Key_Variable=models.CharField(max_length=255,primary_key=True)
    Threshold = models.CharField(max_length=255)
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which is by the way very unclear.

Comment: How can you say it doen t answer the question if you don t unterstand it?

Comment: The OP talks about substraction. Your `eval` should evaluate an addition. Using `eval` is by the way not the best practice. I wonder how did you figure out what the OP really wants (or needs).

Comment: I m just providing an example, I know eval is not good practice but it shows how the magic methods work. I could have written "do something" or whatever that s not the point, I hope this is was what OP meant and hope it will help him.